# How to use the PHP interactive shell

Tags: php, ubuntu, readline, interactive-shell

I'm using [Ubuntu 12.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin) 64 bit, and I want to use the PHP interactive shell:

```
php -a
```

But it doesn't seem to work very well, and a lot of syntax is incorrectly interpreted.

When I run `php -a`, it displays:

> interactive mode enabled

And just a cursor blinking.

I'm using: PHP 5.4.13-2~precise+1 (cli) (built: Mar 21 2013 12:17:18)

How do I use the PHP interactive shell?

Comment: Re *"a lot of syntax is incorrectly interpreted"*: What syntax? Can you provide some examples?

Comment: OK, the OP is gone (*"Last seen more than 8 years ago "*).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try installing [phpsh](https://github.com/facebookarchive/phpsh). It is probably the easiest solution.

*Steps (assuming dependencies are installed):*

1. `git clone https://github.com/facebook/phpsh`
2. `cd phpsh`
3. `sudo python setup.py install`
4. `phpsh`

Answer (score 10):

This is what you'll get when the `php5-readline` package is not installed. Assuming that's your problem you can fix it by running this command:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-readline
```

Comment: You can install it without version specified. I.e. `... install php-readline`. Currently if defaults to some 7.x version.

Answer (score 6):

### How to use the PHP interactive shell

phpsh was made by Facebook. To install it, see *[phpsh -- an interactive shell for PHP](http://www.phpsh.org/)*.

**Installation directions:**

```
sudo apt-get install git
cd /home/youruser;
```

Pull the repository, [cd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)) into it and install:

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/phpsh
cd phpsh
sudo python setup.py install
```

**Run it:**

```
phpsh
```

Session:

```
Starting php
type 'h' or 'help' to see instructions & features
php>
```

**Walkthrough:**

Printing strings:

```
php> echo 'hi';
hi
```

Do some math:

```
php> echo 1+2;

3
```

Print some builtin variables:

```
php> echo $_SERVER;

Array
```

Print contents of that array:

```
php> print_r($_SERVER);

Array
(
    [LANG] => en_US.UTF-8
    [TERM] => xterm
    [SHELL] => /bin/bash
)
```

Get a key of that array:

```
php> echo $_SERVER['TERM'];

xterm
```

Addition of a different kind:

```
php> =2+2

4
```

Print the previous:

```
php> = $_

4
```

Store a variable:

```
php> $msg = "don't just sit there fancy pants, take the wheel";

php> echo $msg;

don't just sit there fancy pants take the wheel
```

An equation can be held open through newlines until it completes:

```
php> =2+
 ... 3+
 ... 4+5
14
```

Define our own arrays:

```
php> $derp = array(1,2,3);

php> echo $derp

Array
```

Get the type of a variable:

```
php> echo gettype(PHP_VERSION);

string
```

For great justice, loops:

```
php> $i = 0; while ($i < 3){$i++; echo "pinkie pie is best pony ";}
pinkie pie is best pony pinkie pie is best pony pinkie pie is best pony
```

Get yourself some information:

```
php> phpinfo();

phpinfo();
PHP Version => 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8
```

Function *[explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)* parses the string on space into an array, and *[print_r()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)* pretty prints it:

```
php> function little_bad_girl(){ print_r(explode(" ", "oxy contin")); }
php> little_bad_girl();

Array
(
    [0] => oxy
    [1] => contin
)
```

A *foreach* structure can be extended onto the following lines.

```
php> foreach (array(1,2,3) as $item) {
 ... echo $item;
 ... }

123
```

Block comments are ignored:

```
php> /* echo "hidden"; */
php>
```

Read from a file:

```
php> $section = file_get_contents('/home/el/myfile.txt');
php> echo $section;

we will become a spacefaring civilization.
```

No, no time:

```
php> echo time();

1386492405
```

Pure sweet truth:

```
php> echo isset($_SERVER);

1
```

Make an array, and search for an item in it.

```
php> $data = array(0, 1, 2);

php> echo preg_grep("/1/", $data);

Array

php> print_r( preg_grep("/1/", $data));

Array
(
    [1] => 1
)

php> print_r( preg_grep("/4/", $data));

Array
(
)
```

Do you want more???  There is enough to fill a lifetime, godspeed: *[PHP and MySQL Tutorials](http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/)*

Answer (score 2):

Use [PsySH](http://psysh.org/):

A little example:

```
psysh

Psy Shell v0.7.2 (PHP 5.5.12-2ubuntu4.6 — cli) by Justin Hileman
```

Session:

```
>>> $toto='ejgf5d78gfmkzl'
=> "ejgf5d78gfmkzl"

>>> substr($toto, 0, 2)
=> "ej"
```